# ¿Cómo elimino los bordes de un iframe?

Tags: html

Quisiera eliminar los bordes de aquí de un **index.html**:

```
<center><iframe src="echo.php"></iframe></center>
```

quiero que solo me quede el texto: de este **texto.php**

```
Echo "Hello work";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los navegadores dan a la etiqueta `<iframe>` unos estilos por defecto, como el borde que comentas.

Puedes quitárselo a través de **CSS** dejando la propiedad `border-width` a 0.

```css
.sin-borde {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Con borde</span>
<iframe src="#"></iframe>
<br>
<span>Sin borde</span>
<iframe src="#" class="sin-borde"></iframe>
```